# Jquery loop throughout ul finding distinct attr('tax')

Tags: jquery

So I've one list element populated with products and I need to calculate the final price, but to do that I need to find witch products have the same tax fee.

Doing this I'm able to isolate them, but how can I make this automatically? I mean, If I don't know the tax fee how can I find different taxes and join them?

Hope my english is good to make myself clear.

Thanks

```
$('#list').find('li').each(function(i) {
    if($(this).attr('tax') == 6) {
        console.log('6');
    } else if($(this).attr('tax') == 13) {
        console.log('13');
    } else if($(this).attr('tax') == 23) {
        console.log('23');
    } else { }
});
```

Comment: So you want to find out what tax is on each list item and them add them all up into a single variable?

Comment: Or do you want to group each element with the same tax into an array?

Comment: I want to find what tax is on each list item, so I can then calculate per example 10 items within tax(?) = €...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a closure in a way like this to group li items and then cycle through the object to do your calculations (or do it in only one pass if is simpler...)

```
function calc_prices()
{
  var tax_groups = {};
  $('#list').find('li').each(function(i) {

    if(!tax_groups[$(this).attr('tax')]) tax_groups[$(this).attr('tax')] = [];
    tax_groups[$(this).attr('tax')].push($(this));
  });
  console.log(tax_groups);
  //Do your math here by looping or accessing tax_groups
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This will create a 'data' object, whose properties are the different tax values, and the value of each property is an array of the matching DOM elements.

```
var data = {};

$('#list').find('li').each(function(i) {
  var tax = $(this).attr('tax');
  if(!data[tax]) data[tax] = [];

  var len = data[tax].length;
  data[tax][len] = this;
});
```

Comment: but what about if I don't know the tax value?